# having multiple problems while working with bootstrap in react in fact of importing all necessary imports

Tags: css, reactjs

i have multiple question , so here is the code

`import React from "react"

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

function Nav()
{

return (

```
<div className="container-fluid nav_bg">

  <div className="row">

    <div className="col-10 mx-auto">

      <nav
        activeClassName="menu_active"
        className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"
      >
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="#">
            {" "}
            BRILLICA SERVICES
          </NavLink>
          <button
            activeClassName="menu_active"
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span
              activeClassName="menu_active"
              className="navbar-toggler-icon"
            ></span>
          </button>
          <div>
            className="collapse navbar-collapse"
            id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink
                  activeClassName="menu_active"
                  className="nav-link active"
                  aria-current="page"
                  to="/home"
                >
                  Home
                </NavLink>
              </li>

              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink
                  activeClassName="menu_active"
                  className="nav-link"
                  to="/services"
                >
                  Services
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink
                  activeClassName="menu_active"
                  className="nav-link"
                  to="/about"
                >
                  About us
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <NavLink
                  activeClassName="menu_active"
                  className="nav-link"
                  to="/Contact"
                >
                  Contact us
                </NavLink>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

);
}
export default Nav;`

now my question :

1. in the ul tag there is a ml-auto (which will give margin left-auto ) , but i want to give margin right -auto , so in place of ml-auto i inserted mr-auto but it isn't working , in my browser when i run the same piece of code in codeply and in codepen it works .
2. in the same project i created a new file [home.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOpez.png) i give it perfect css of how i want but it is again same , it isn't working.
   so, please help

Comment: Where's the working codeply?

Answer (score 0):

Highly suggest you look into using [styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components). Tough to say what's happening here.

Comment: it is only not working while starting the development server in react , otherwise it is working in codeply .